# My computer boots directly to windows 8.1 after installing Ubuntu14.02

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I have a Dell inspiron 5521 and I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside my windows but there seems to be a problem and I'm not quite sure that it has anything to do with my partitioning.

Right now I have four partitions in this order:

1. Windows boot ntfs  about 300 MB
2. Windows      ntfs  about 800 GB
3. Ubuntu       ext4  about 50 GB
4. Ubuntu swap  swap  about 4 GB

First I installed my windows 8.1 and then installed Ubuntu 14.02 on third and fourth partitions but my computer goes directly to Windows.

Is it my partitioning or it's something else, and if so what should I do?

Comment: Are you using EFI or legacy boot in your bios? Did you install grub correctly?

Comment: You've provided insufficient detail for a meaningful answer. Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (available in the `boot-info-script` package). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL to your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can install "boot repair" to fix the problem and try to install "grub 2.0", if the problem persist try to disable fast boot and enable UEFI MODE

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit the BCD file on windows, with a BCD editor and configure it to start from the linux partition, from there the grub menu will appear and provide you with the option of what system you want to start